# Change table header color using boxable with pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, datatable, pdfbox, boxable

I am using boxable with pdfbox to make table in pdf. It worked fine. Only thing, I need to change header color and cell style.

I am using below code. Please suggest

```
List<List> data = new ArrayList();
data.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three", "Column Four", "Column Five")));
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
{
    data.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Row " + i + " Col One", "Row " + i + " Col Two", "Row " + i + " Col Three", "Row " + i + " Col Four", "Row " + i + " Col Five")));
    BaseTable dataTable = new BaseTable(yStart, yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, doc, page, true, true);
    DataTable t = new DataTable(dataTable, page);
    t.addListToTable(data, DataTable.HASHEADER);
    dataTable.draw();
}
```

Comment: Hi Tilman,   Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: No, I just added and created the label because this lib is used here sometimes. I'm only a PDFBox committer. Maybe your answer is here? http://github.com/dhorions/boxable/wiki#various-table-layout-styles

Comment: I cant find this method getLayouters

Comment: I'm sorry. I trusted their documentation. You are right... there's even an issue about that: https://github.com/dhorions/boxable/issues/97 It is implemented in this branch: https://github.com/dhorions/boxable/tree/api-SoC so you'd have to build yourself.

Comment: i fix it. I found solution of this..

Comment: Then please answer the question yourself (this is OK).

Answer (score 1):

```
t.getDataCellTemplateEven().setFillColor(Color.WHITE);
t.getDataCellTemplateOdd().setFillColor(Color.WHITE);
t.getHeaderCellTemplate().setFillColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Where t is object of DataTable class.
The Color class is of AWT and you can change it however you want. So no need to edit the library.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code in table.java in boxable code.

in line as below

PDStreamUtils.rect(tableContentStream, margin, yStart, width, headerBottomMargin, Color.GRAY);